# strange migration from django to postgres DB. How to save an exist data

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, inspectdb

I have walking on a strange way, but it is result of circumstances. 
I had to been  generate single models.py from exist postgres DB by inspect_db.
Next I fix some field (was a few problem with keys), and create 2 apps inside this project. So now I have 3 models.py (them are split models.py, whitch was generate by inspect_db). `managed = True` was added. Classes have same links and datatypes like in the database
Next I wish to integrate this models to exist database. I make migration, I migrate and in the end DB have only system django tables (auth_, django_migrations etc.) None from my classes (although migrate files were create). So I tryied to delete migrations catalogs and repeat `makemigrations` and `migrate`, but terminal threw it:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
(forest-venv) user@user-HP-Z800-Workstation ~/MyProjects/forest-venv/lesoved $ python manage.py runserver 8001
Performing system checks...
```

If I try make migrates again - no changes. I tryied to delete info about my apps in django_migrations table - no result.

So my questions:
- It is possible to integrate new models into exist database (if names, keyes and formats is ok)?
- Integration is possible by the way where data from exist database is saved after migrations?
- How to return possobillity of make migrations? now it isn't work.

Comment: First you need to reach a state where your models and migrations match your db. Don't change anything to the models made by `inspectdb`. If your models match your db, you should `makemigrations`, then for your apps run `migrate <app> --fake` and then `migrate` (for the django apps, assuming your db doesn't have `auth` etc...). Then you can start changing models and migrating as usual.

Comment: @dirkgroten so if i did changes in model before makemigrations and migrate i will not integrate models into exist database?

Comment: No you first need to make sure your current migration state matches your db state. Otherwise you can’t run the `fake` mode.  Btw you should make sure your db doesn’t have migrations (django-migrations table) before you start.

Comment: @dirkgroten thanks! So, if I understood you correctly, I have to: 1)generate inspect_db models.py; 2)don't change this models.py and to do makemigrations; 3) to do migrate <app> --fake and to do whole migrate; 4) Next, in the end i can to divide this models.py on few models  in different  app of my project. Yes?

Comment: Amazing, all are work! Thanks @dirkgroten and django documentation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick when using an existing database is to make sure you start from a well-defined state: First get Django to the exact same state as your db, and only after that start making changes to your models. So these are the steps:

1. Check that your database doesn't have a `django-migrations` table, delete it using SQL if needed. (Note: I'm assuming this db isn't generated by Django to start with and you're creating a fresh django application)
2. Create your models with `inspectdb`. If needed, rename the models to have proper *CamelCase*. If you rename models or fields that would change the table or column name in the db, make sure to set `db_table` (`Meta` options of your model) and `db_column` (as field attribute).
3. Run `manage.py makemigrations`. Check the migration files for your models, just to be sure the names match with your db.
4. For your own apps, run `manage.py migrate <app> --fake`. This will add the migrations to `django-migrations` table in your db as if they ran, without actually running them.
5. Then run `manage.py migrate` to create the django provided tables (`auth`, `contenttype`, `session` etc...)
6. Now you are at the state where you can start changing things. If you change the model and run `makemigrations` it should create a migration just for your changes.